# Is there any other use of naming a function that is being assigned other than recursive calling itself?

Tags: javascript, function

If I say:

```
let F = function G(){}
```

What is destination of identifier `G`?

Is there any other reason to name it other than use it for recursion?

Is there a way that I could access identifier `G`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of functions is shown in the stack trace, if there is an exception thrown.

[image]

The name will typically also be shown in the debugger's scope window:

[image]

For these two reasons, naming anonymous functions can make debugging easier, especially when dealing with complex call structures with many anonymous functions.

If for some reason, you want to access the name of the function, you can do so with `F.name`

Comment: wouldn't be better to just use `function F(){}` instead? is there a good reason to do things differently? Because doing so would allow recursion, would facilitate debugging... what are the pros in doing the other way around?

Comment: For all the normal reasons one might want to declare a function with an assignment statement rather than a hoisted function declaration.